# iOS delegate and Singleton pattern

Tags: ios, singleton, delegation, cocoa-design-patterns

I am developing an iOS application. My used design pattern Singleton and Delegation patterns. I did nil a delegate object in dealloc method. If user re opened this screen and set to  delegate object self. But I see delegate object always nil. How can I re assign to self to delegate object

Comment: It's impossible to diagnose this from a description. Please post some code.

Comment: Where you are reassigning your delegate to self?

Comment: Actually my problem delegate object do not re assign? I want to re assign to delegate object

Answer (score 2):

Since your question is not detailed,
I would like to give you suggestion to double-check your singleton code first and 
check whether of not your delegate is properly set along with your logic in the right way always.
I know this is too broad and general answer, However, it cannot be helped.
For reference, This Below code is Basic structure of Objective-C singleton under ARC.(for swift version, check the above answers.)

YourSingleton.h

```
@interface YourSingleton : NSObject

+ (YourSingleton*)sharedInstance;

@end
```

YourSingleton.m

```
#import "YourSingleton.h"

@implementation YourSingleton

#pragma mark - singleton method

+ (YourSingleton*)sharedInstance
{
    static dispatch_once_t predicate = 0;
    __strong static id sharedObject = nil;
    dispatch_once(&predicate, ^{
        sharedObject = [[self alloc] init];
    });
    return sharedObject;
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this in your singleton Class method

```
//Strict impelmentation of singleton with ARC.
//Object is created only once in the System.
static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
    if(myObject==nil){
        myObject= [[myClass alloc]init];
    }
});

return sharedEffcoreObject;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should ask the question more briefly. You can find information about most of design patterns, and how to implement them on ios [here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/46988/ios-design-patterns). 
Hope this helps.